# Vacuously prove that the empty set is a subset of any set $A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

My proof is as follows: For any given set $A$, $A\cap \emptyset=\emptyset\implies \emptyset\subseteq A$

Is this a valid proof? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I guess. But if you want to be very vigorous (and simple), I would suggest that you go from the definition of subset relation. That is, for all $x\in \varnothing$, we have  $x \in A$. Because you use a fact ($if A\subset A\cap B$, then $A\subset B$), which I think can be proved.

Answer (score 6):

That makes sense, although I don't think that's "vacuous." What they want you to see is the following:

In order to show $\emptyset\subseteq A$, you must show that if $x\in\emptyset$, then $x\in A$. But $\emptyset$ has no elements, so the statement is vacuously true.